# Why does "git diff" compare a file against /dev/null?

Tags: git

I'm trying to compare a single file on a branch with the same file on another branch.  I have been referencing the answers from similar questions, but I'm unable to get anything to work, and I've tried this on two different systems, using different versions of git.  I get different failures on each system.

I have a feeling the problem is that the branch I'm comparing against looks like a revision number.  The branch name is "2.2.0".

On one system, running git v2.17.0, I see this:

```
% git diff -b 2.2.0 my-branch -- stuff.groovy 
diff --git a/vars/stuff.groovy b/vars/stuff.groovy
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..c6a2073
--- /dev/null
+++ b/vars/stuff.groovy
@@ -0,0 +1,84 @@
```

This proceeds to cat out the entire contents of the file, each line prefaced with "+ ", which is obvious, as it's comparing against "/dev/null".  I have no idea why it is doing that.

On another system running git v2.7.4, instead of the other output, I see only this line:

```
fatal: bad revision '2.2.0'
```

I can do this comparison in Eclipse, which uses the JGit library, not the "git" command line, and it works perfectly fine, showing the one line between these branches that is different.

**Update**:

Adding results from the following commands:

```
% git branch
  2.2.0
* cart-checkout-customizations
  master
% git tag
% git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 2.2.0
refs/heads/2.2.0
```

**Update**:

Adding output from another command for diagnostics:

```
% git branch -a
  2.2.0
* cart-checkout-customizations
  master
  remotes/origin/2.2.0
  remotes/origin/bugfix/pr-issue
  remotes/origin/cart-checkout-customizations
  remotes/origin/dp5252/func_get_job_details_textgroovy-1560980842574
  remotes/origin/dp5252/pl_idp_msgroovy-1560289622641
  remotes/origin/dp5252/pl_idp_msgroovy-1560979038086
  remotes/origin/dp5252/stage_build_docker_imagegroovy-1559338261549
  remotes/origin/feature/2.2.0-temp
  remotes/origin/feature/2.2.1
  remotes/origin/feature/cfgrole-playbook
  remotes/origin/feature/disable-concurrent-builds
  remotes/origin/feature/hpa
  remotes/origin/feature/hygieia
  remotes/origin/feature/istio
  remotes/origin/feature/notify-stash
  remotes/origin/feature/profile-pipeline-id
  remotes/origin/feature/sast
  remotes/origin/feature/sast-swap
  remotes/origin/feature/scrumboard-removal
  remotes/origin/feature/smoke-test-fix
  remotes/origin/feature/temp-investigation
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/trackingaudit
```

If it isn't obvious, the current branch is "cart-checkout-customizations", which is the "my-branch" I refer to elsewhere.  The actual file name isn't "stuff.groovy", but that doesn't matter.

**Update**:

And to be clear, the sample command provided by @ZachPosten works.  I hope that provides a useful clue to someone.  It really does look like the original commands resulted in git thinking that "2.2.0" is NOT a branch, but something else.  The form that makes it explicit that it is a branch name (by prefacing it with "origin/"), somehow made it work.

Comment: Please add the output of `git branch`, `git tag`, and/or `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 2.2.0`.

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have a local branch `2.2.0`?

Perhaps try

```
git diff origin/2.2.0 origin/my-branch -- stuff.groovy
```

Seeing the output of `git branch -a` would be helpful to diagnose this.

**Update**:

I see that you do have both a local and remote `2.2.0` branch.  My guess would then be that they point to different commits, and that's why the local branch reference fails while the remote one succeeds.

It could also be possible that another identifier `2.2.0` exists in your repo, as you suggest.  To figure this out, you can run:

```
$ git show-ref 2.2.0

21787341c2e651b17d94375ecb1137b575a2099e refs/heads/2.2.0
21787341c2e651b17d94375ecb1137b575a2099e refs/remotes/up/2.2.0
a2d88e63057d7ae1484a90d36ee5b12fc78828cd refs/tags/2.2.0
```

Here you can see that I have three references to `2.2.0` in my repository, a local branch (`refs/heads`), a remote branch (`refs/remotes`), and a tag (`refs/tags`).  The branches point to the same commit but the tag points to a different one.

Comment: Interesting. This command worked.  It gave me the diff output I expected.  I'll update the OP with the output from "git branch -a".

Comment: Ok.  This was the key problem.  The local "2.2.0" and the remote "2.2.0" were in fact on different commits.  I also tried changing the original command line to use "origin/2.2.0" instead of "2.2.0", and now that provides the expected output, and after switching to "2.2.0" and doing a pull, the original command gives me the expected output.

Comment: OK, yeah, there's only one local name `2.2.0`, so the branch name takes priority. If there were multiple `2.2.0`s the one that takes priority is a bit tricky (but that wasn't the case here). `origin/2.2.0` resolves to the commit identified by `refs/remotes/origin/2.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the file does not exist and for diff to work properly there needs to be a file, so the `empty file` /dev/null is used.

You could also try to use the commit hash of the last commits in both branches...

Have you tried to do `git diff 2.2.0..my-branch`?

From the git documentation `man git diff`

> Comparing branches
>
> ```
>            $ git diff topic master    (1)
>            $ git diff topic..master   (2)
>            $ git diff topic...master  (3)
>
>        1. Changes between the tips of the topic and the master branches.
>        2. Same as above.
>        3. Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it.
> ```

Comment: That would make sense if it were actually true. As I said at the end, the comparison in Eclipse works perfectly fine. And yes, I've tried those alternate forms. They compare all files with "/dev/null" and provide the same nonsense results.

Comment: I just tried diffing two branches, if I do `git diff 2.2.0 master` it works as it should. Are you sure, that the file `stuff.groovy` exists in both branches? Is the file maybe just staged within one branch and eclipse shows the diff to the staged version?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. That's why the Eclipse comparison works. And just to be absolutely sure, I just inspected the file in our BitBucket server instance and toggled between the two branches to view the difference.